# How to handle great number of mapper's key in a Hadoop program?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The mapping phase of my Hadoop program generates a great number of unique keys (around 200K keys for one data set and 900K for another data set). Each key is a string value containing 60 numerical characters. The sorting/shuffling phase of the my Hadoop program takes too long. Is there any way to make the sorting/shuffling phase more efficient for such a great number of keys?

Comment: Are you literally using a `String` value for your key?  Have you considered using a numeric type that implements `Comparable<BinaryComparable>`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Text as the mapper's key type. I can change it to IntWritable, do I need to implement the ``Comparable`` in that case or not? As I believe IntWritable does the comparison in byte level, Am I right?

Comment: You do not need to implement Comparable, and if you can change the key to a more "compact" type, it would be OK, consider `VIntWritable` or `VLongWritable`, both of them save memory allocation space on integers.

Comment: @Diego Jimeno according to this JavaDoc, keys should be `WritableComparable`, which extends `Comparable`.  Keys definitely have to be compared to be sorted.  I suggested `BinaryComparable` because the Hadoop documentation states that comparing binary values is generally faster than Text values.  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the use of combiners to reduce the overheat of the network, combining the "map-phase" outputs sent over to reducers.

You are right as regarding to WritableComparator, is better to implement yours, because as far as I know the way of comparing two objects in sort phase is by, once serialized the objects(output from the mapper), Hadoop in order to give and order, have to deserialize them, so It is pretty much better to avoid the "deserialization phase" and do the comparison at byte level.

You have to be careful on overriding the method `compare` from `WritableComparable`, because can be pretty challenging to do it properly, the method I'm referring to from `GrepCode`:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparator.java#WritableComparator.compare%28byte%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cbyte%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29

**EDIT**

I add which I consider a great article, to take some pointers on improving the performance on MapReduce:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/12/7-tips-for-improving-mapreduce-performance/

Comment: combiners don't help much when there are lots of unique keys and the groups are small.

Comment: does changing the key from Text to another data type like IntWritable help?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a custom key type.  There are a few reasons for this:

- By having a numeric (binary) key, you can implement `Comparable<BinaryComparable>`, which compares bytes instead of text, allowing for a speed increase
- You can have the key writable as a binary format, which saves time when transmitting and reading the key.  If we were to write a key class, we could extend `BytesWritable`, which already implements the interface that I mentioned in the first bullet.

There are some job parameters that you should probably tune.  For instance, you might want to consider tuning the `io.sort` options within your job.  Because you have a lot of unique values, Hadoop probably isn't able to sort them all in memory, meaning that it must spill to the disk.  When this happens, the data must be re-read and re-sorted, slowing down the shuffle.  You can tell if spills are happening by looking through your log since spills are recorded.  For tuning tips, see http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/mr-perf